# How to capture output from Ruby script to Powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell

How can I redirect the output from Ruby back into the calling Powershell script?

Here's my code snippet:

```
$powershell_variable = & [path to ruby.exe] ruby_script.rb $arg1 $arg2
```

The script runs fine but I expect to get the response from the script into `$powershell_variable`, which doesn't work.